# What's an adjective I can use when my fingerprint doesn't work for scanners?

Tags: word-choice

So when you're at the airport or somewhere else, we need to put our fingers and make the fingerprint scanners recognize ours.

But my fingerprint is too ***adjective***, and the fingerprint scanner won't recognize mine. I always experience this situation whenever I have to use these fingerprint scanners.

Someone has a fingerprint that is very clear(or strong, evident? I don't know what adjective I should use here either), so the scanner works very well. But mine is very vague/invisible/blurred or whatever...(I don't think any of these adjectives fits here.) so I have to retry over and over till it can finally read mine.

What adjective can I use in this situation? My fingerprint is ***sth*.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most appropriate words that are the opposite of strong/clear are

[faint](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/faint): not strong or clear; slight

[blurred](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blurred):  difficult to see

[indistinct](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/indistinct): not clear

In principle, you could also use **unclear**, but in my opinion the word is mainly used about something that is not obvious, difficult to understand or uncertain. If you look at the examples in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unclear) and the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unclear) you will see that this is largely true.

The main problem with fingerprint reading, though,  is that the reader relies on a certain amount of moisture in your skin to detect the ridges of your fingerprint. If your fingers are very dry one day and very moist the next, the detected fingerprint will differ from day to day. The best word to describe this is:

[inconsistent](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inconsistent) If a reason, idea, opinion, etc. is inconsistent, different parts of it do not agree, or it does not agree with something else

Comment: or "unclear" is a simple opposite of clear

Comment: @JamesK, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So you're saying it is best to say "my fingerprint is *inconsistent*", right?" But if my fingerprint is *actually* more indistinct than other people, (cause the scanners *always* don't read mine) then can I say my fingerprint is more *indistinct/blurred* than others'?

Comment: @dbwlsld: You could say that your fingerprint is more inconsistent, or less consistent. You could also use **more indistinct**. There is actually an adjective **blurry**, so you can also say **blurrier**. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blurry